# Why when we add negative numbers to negative numbers in equation it is zero, but in (-3)+(-3)=3 it is positive?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Why this is like this.
I don't understand why when we add $+(-3)$ to both sides on left side of equation $(-3)+(-3)$ is zero?
But in ordinary $-3+(-3)=-6$.

$$\begin{align}
1−(−3) \;&=\;   b \\
 +(−3) \;&\phantom{=}\;      +(−3) \\
\hline
1      \;&=\;   b+(−3) \\[8pt]
​b &=4
\end{align}$$

Comment: -3+(-3)=-6 i am dumb sorry

Comment: $(-3)+(-3)$ isn't an equation, it's an expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have $-3 + (-3)$, but $-(-3) + (-3)$, which equals $0$.

Comment: so -(-3) is 3 ?, why?